# Org Mode Code Sessions Scope

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I'm trying to use sessions within an org file to keep the code workspace as I need something similar in style to the Jupyter Notebooks. The issue I'm having is this isn't restricting the session to have the scope only on the current org file.

The example is if I have a file `a.org` containing

```
#+begin_src python :results output replace :session default
a = 5
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :results output replace :session default
print(a)
#+end_src
```

and another file `b.org`

```
#+begin_src python :results output replace :session default
print(a)
#+end_src
```

The code from `b.org` uses the same session defined in `a.org`, while printing the same  as the second block. This is an issue because if I have to use a different kernel for `b.org`, it uses the kernel that `a.org` is using. I would like to use the same session *name*, but have the underlying sessions not be recognized outside of the file.

This is regardless of whether there is a property tag specifying the session name.

Comment: The session name becomes the name of the buffer that the session runs in. Since buffers are global objects in Emacs, the only way to disambiguate the buffers is to disambiguate the session names. So the solution is to indeed provide a property  specifying a different session name for each file.

Comment: Is there a way to list all sessions defined, like there is a buffer list?

Comment: Not that I know. You can maybe apply some heuristics on the buffer list, but it would be a best guess: there is nothing that distinguishes a session created from a code block in an org mode file from a similar session created from the command line.